# Split a string into multiple rows

Tags: sql, string, split, apply

how I can split a string into multiple rows but without using an input table, just a string?

Example, the string is 'abc,grt,asd,eee,78s'

The output should be like this:

abc

grt

asd

eee

78s

I see here many solutions, but all using a table where the one or more input strings are stored.

How can i achieve this without using a table?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you're struggling because your data hasn't been properly normalized.

Comment: What type & version of database is this for?

Answer (score 0):

Create the below function .

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
 (    
  @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @Character CHAR(1)
 )
 RETURNS @Output TABLE (
   Item NVARCHAR(1000)
  )
 AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

   SET @StartIndex = 1
   IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
   BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
   END

   WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
   BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
     END

    RETURN
    END
    GO
```

Using the below query you can split your string.

```
 SELECT Item
 FROM dbo.SplitString('abc,grt,asd,888,78s', ',')
```